# Cauchy Schwarz Inequality with probability density function!

Tags: measure-theory

$$\left\lvert\int_a^b x(t) y^{\ast}(t) p(t) dt\right\rvert^2 \leq  \int_a^b |x(t)|^2 p(t) dt \int_a^b |y(t)|^2 p(t) dt$$

where $p$ is a PDF: $p(t)\geq 0$, almost everywhere in $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b p(t) dt = 1$.

Can any one guide me, how to proof this inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with the functions $f\colon t\mapsto x(t)\sqrt{p(t)}$ and $g\colon  t\mapsto y^*(t)\sqrt{p(t)}$.

Comment: Can you kindly suggests any reference for your proposed method?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Recall that $(A-B)^2 \geq 0$ implies

$$A \cdot B \leq \frac{A^2}{2}+ \frac{B^2}{2}$$

for any $A,B \geq 0$. Apply this inequality to

$$A := \frac{|x(t)|}{\|x\|_2} \qquad \quad B := \frac{|y(t)|}{\|y\|_2}$$

and integrate both sides with respect to $p(t) \, dt$. Here

$$\|x\|_2 := \left( \int_a^b |x(t)|^2 \, p(t) dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

denotes the $L^2$-norm with respect to $p(t) \, dt$.